# C++ convert between Byte vector and wstring

Tags: c++, vector, byte, arrays, widestring

I need to process the data stored in wide strings at a low level. I am able to convert to a `vector` of `Bytes` with the following method:

```
typedef unsigned char Byte;

wstring mystring = L"my wide string";
Byte const *pointer = reinterpret_cast<Byte const*>(&mystring[0]);
size_t size = mystring.size() * sizeof(mystring.front());
vector<Byte> byteVector(pointer, pointer + size);
```

However, I am having trouble going the other way; I am not very familiar with casting. How do I convert a `vector` of `Bytes` to a `wstring`?

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring wstring_convert_from_char( const char *str )
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes( str );
}

std::string string_convert_from_wchar( const wchar_t *str )
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> converter;
    return converter.to_bytes( str );
}

std::wstring wstring_convert_from_bytes( const std::vector< char > &v )
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes( v.data(), v.data() + v.size() );
}

std::vector< char > wstring_convert_to_bytes( const wchar_t *str )
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> converter;
    std::string string = converter.to_bytes( str );
    return std::vector< char >( string.begin(), string.end() );
}
```

Comment: +1 for the great answer. One question though: I am using these method on Ubuntu 16.04 with g++ 5.4.0 - Isn't it requires to compile with C++11 and the header file `<locale>` ? Thanks !!

Comment: @GuyAvraham Good question, but honestly I'm not familiar with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this
`mystring.assign(reinterpret_cast<wstring::const_pointer>(&byteVector[0]), byteVector.size() / sizeof(wstring::value_type));`